# In browser, how to detect what event is triggered by interacting with a button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm using vue, bootstrap 4, and bootstrap-vue.

I'm trying to fix a visual bug that appears when I click on a button (see attached animated screenshot).
the bug is visible by looking at the bottom part of the table, **it shouldn't have additional whitespace at the bottom**.

I believe there is some JavaScript under the hood that manipulates the appearance of the table.

**How can I find the function that triggers `onMouseOver` when I move the pointer over the `"download" button?**

[image: Download button issue in Chrome]

---

**UPDATE**

By following the advice I've tried to replicate the issue in **Firefox**.

The issue seems being there but in a slightly different fashion, see attached animated screenshot.

I have a sense the problem might be in the popper.js used by bootstrap to inject elements in the DOM.

The "download" button has been built by using bootstrap-vue, so it might be anything added from that.

In the meantime I'm trying to recreate the button with vanilla bootstrap. Wish me luck.

[image: Download button issue in Firefox]

---

**Further Update**

It seems like popper.js looks for the closest parent with the css rule `overflow: [something];` and detects the dropdown position from that. By doing so in some browsers (Chrome does it differently than Firefox, AFAIK) it makes the scrollbar appear even though there is nothing to scroll to, hence the empty white space.

The solution I put in place is to avoid to use popper.js and use a custom made component instead. Not ideal, but it will do for time being.

Thanks everyone for your contribution.

Comment: I'd start by inspecting the HTML and observe what causes the layout change,and then looking for references to causes for that layout change, rather than going the other way around

Comment: Thanks, @CertainPerformance I've inspected the DOM and I see the button and its dropdown menu being injected in the DOM tree but I don't see any change on the table itself. I'm inclined to think there must be some css side-effecting something.  Hence I would like to see what is actually going on with that function.

Comment: You might find better luck using firebug/firefox dev tools. They have a cool feature that allows you to see what events are bound to what. Chrome doesn't have this out of the box.

Comment: @mwilson that's interesting. Do you have a link to some documentation I can look at?

Comment: Alright, I found the event by following what @mwilsonsuggested. There is a function in `popper.js` that adds a scrollbar to the closest parent that has `overflow: scroll;` which in this case is the table.  If I remove the class that makes the table scrollable the body gets the scrollbar. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by using Firefox's dev tools to inspect the DOM. The reason why I say firefox is because it's got a cool feature that will show you any events bound to that element. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners) for details

It's capable of detecting the following events:

- Standard DOM Events
- jQuery Events
- React Events

[image]

Comment: Chrome has event inspection too.

Comment: Alright, I found the event by following what you mentioned. There is a function in `popper.js` that adds a scrollbar to the closest parent that has `overflow: scroll;` which in this case is the table.  If I remove the class that makes the table scrollable the body gets the scrollbar. Weird.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you point out a link to how to inspect events in chrome? :)

Comment: @Adriano I'm about 99.9% confident chrome dev tools don't have the ability to see what events are hooked up to what. Hence the mentioning of firefox here. I use chrome as my primary browser in both dev/normal usage. If this feature exists it is extremely hidden. There's probably some extension though (which is probably what LawrenceCherone is talking about). Also, friendly reminder to upvote answers that help.